# Connect Microsoft SharePoint to Linux server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, linux

I am new to sharepoint and I created a web page in SharePoint. I want to make connectivity to this page with linux server. So that we can run some commands from SharePoint (send that command to linux server and execute from there) and we can read from Linux server into SharePoint page.

Is it very complex? Or can we write small script where we can pass the server name and userid/ password to connect Linux server. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I have post this to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666511/connect-microsoft-sharepoint-to-linux-server too.

**Edit**

We have created a web page in SharePoint. We want to create a button and when we click on this button, it will execute a script on Linux server and will produce the report. If it will be easy to fetch report from Linux server directly then we will pull the reports from Linux server to Microsoft SharePoint and publish.

Comment: What's the business motivation here? What is the end game?

Comment: GavinB - I have update the question above. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Have you considered creating a web service on your linux box and then writing a SharePoint Web Part that consumes the web service?  You can get the current user credentials via the object model, but I'm not sure about your security requirements about sending a password from your windows domain to your linux domain..

Comment: In principle @JeffFreeman's approach is solid. If you need to store a username and password to authenticate the call to the external web service then take a look at teh Secure Store Service to hold those for you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much SharePoint specificity in this question, I think.

The button on your SharePoint page may perform one of the following client-side actions:

1. Add or set SRC attribute of an IFRAME on the page to display a resource from the Linux server to the user
2. Send an asynchronous AJAX request to a resource on the Linux server and process the result.

Depending on your needs, you could also implement some server-side communication with the Linux server, but that should be unnecessary in most scenarios.